# Как объявить несколько независимых локальных хранилищ на одном домене?

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Я сохраняю данные из формы в локальное хранилище, а затем отправляю на сервер. В случае потери соединения данные должны быть записаны в другое хранилище, чтобы затем, при восстановлении подключения - отправить их, и перенести в первое хранилище(успешное).
Такой вариант не работает, т.к. оба хранилища ссылаются на один объект.

```
SucessStorage = localStorage;
UnsucessStorage = localStorage;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю если тебе надо ветвить хранилище, почему бы не использовать . в названии переменной, например:

```
localStorage.setItem("success.some", 1);
localStorage.setItem("unsuccess.some", 2);
console.log(localStorage['success.some']);
console.log(localStorage['unsuccess.some']);
```

Иначе ветвления нет. Есть правда ещё sessionStorage но не советовал бы костылить и писать в них строго по категории данных.

Comment: К такому варианту я сам пришел. Если не найдется другого решения, то я им конечно воспользуюсь. Но минусов у него полно. 1)Когда буду отправлять данные после возобновления соединения, необходимо будет находить в хранилище данные с определенной последовательностью в ключе(флагом, "unsuccess" например). Затем, после успешной отправки менять флаг на "success", при этом сохраняя нумерацию! Довольно не просто и ресурсоемко. 2)Локальное хранилище со временем будет наполняться, там может оказаться и 500 и 2000 записей, и все их придется каждый раз перебирать!!

Comment: Если напрягает - есть например решение расширить прототип Storage( `localStorage instanceof Storage  = true` ). Напимер добавить методы setBranch , getBranch , и переопределить другие методы. Или написать свою обёртку. Storage  - это средство, в конце концов - собственный оборачивающий класс написать - это норма.

Comment: А можно на этом месте поподробнее? Без примера не могу в полной мере понять.

Comment: @PavelSaenko Вариант с префиксами для ключей самый простой. Решение можно упростить, если отказаться от хранения данных из формы в случае успешной отправки. Если данные успешно отправлены - зачем их хранить в хранилище? В голову приходит только один вариант - для автозаполнения этой формы. Но в этом случае наверное имеет смысл хранить не 2 комплекта данных, а один - то что ввел пользователь последним + служебный 1 флаг успешно отправили данные или нет.

Comment: @M.Onyshchuk Полностью с Вами согласен. Я тоже не понимаю зачем хранить отправленные данные. Но не мне решать. Задание сформулировала руководитель производственной практики. Я сразу ей сказал ,что было бы куда проще отказаться от хранения отправленных данных. Наверно стоит еще раз с ней поговорить. (Пара слов о самом задании: web приложение ASP MVC, для портового планшетного терминала: в форму забиваются данные груза(номер, заказчик и т.д.) и отправляются на сервер. Если соединение пропало - данные сохраняются локально и каждые 30 сек снова пытаются передаться)

Answer (score 1):

Кстати. В DevExtreme есть очень интересная фишка.

```
var store = new DevExpress.data.LocalStore({
                name: "MyLocalData",
                key: "id",
                customfield: "Ваше поле"
            });
```

таким образом в локальном хранилище создается запись с клюем dx-data-LocalStore - name, в значении которого хранятся необходимые поля. Количество полей не ограничено. Далее, используя доступные методы записи, обновления, сортировки и т.д. можно пользоваться этой записью как полноценным хранилищем. И таких хранилищ может быть сколь угодно много. Получается LocalStorage внутри LocalStorage.

Comment: фактически это реализация идеи из соседнего ответа, просто обертка над localStorage